# Notificaciones push de app a app

Tags: php, android-studio, firebase, app, notificaciones

no encuentro información de como enviar notificaciones push en android studio desde una app "servidor" a varias app.

Les platico rapido de esta app,  pues es un tipo periodico donde solo una app manda las noticias cada que el administrador lo necesite y esta noticia le llega a todos los que tengan la app instalada en su cel ya esta todo hecho pero nadie le avisa a los usuarios que tienen una nuevas noticia, lo que necesito es que cada que el administrador envie una nueva noticia le llegue una notificacion push al todos los que tengan a app, (osea una notificacion en la barra de estado o un chat head o un numerito en el icono de la app ya sea con sonido luz vibracion etc etc o no).

Answer (score 0):

La solucion definitiva es usar firebase cloud messaging, con solo un par de linease puedes montar un servicio de push notifications para todos tus usuarios

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/?hl=es-419